# 各国言語（日本語、英語、ドイツ語、・・・）のOS毎（win、mac)の標準ゴシックフォントを知りたい

Tags: html, css, font

各国言語（日本語、英語、ドイツ語、フランス語、イタリア語、スペイン語、ポルトガル語、韓国語、中国語、ロシア語など）のOS毎（win、mac)の標準ゴシックフォントを国毎に切り替えられるようにしたいのですが、国毎の標準ゴシックフォントはどのようになっているのでしょうか。フォント名を知りたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ゴシック体というのは日本語など東アジア圏特有のものなので、それ以外の言語・地域にはありません。

実際に欲しいのは CSS 標準の [`sans-serif`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#sans-serif-def) フォントファミリーか、[`system-ui`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#system-ui-def) フォントファミリーではないでしょうか。こういった総称フォントファミリー名を指定すると、ブラウザが表示する言語に従って適切なフォントを選んでくれます。

参考までに、Chromeブラウザのデフォルトの`sans-serif`フォントファミリーの実際のフォント名は[IDS_SANS_SERIF_FONT_FAMILYで検索](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=IDS_SANS_SERIF_FONT_FAMILY%20file:%5C.grd&sq=&ss=chromium&originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F)すると見ることができます。

Comment: PingFangやMicrosoft YaHei、Tahomaなどのようなものが各国にあるものだと思っておりましたが、確かに、欧米圏では共通かもしれませんね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @x001017 さん、各国語にそれっぽいフォントがないわけではないですが、sans-serifを指定すればじゅうぶんだろう、という意味です。少々追記しました。